# How to update the state of the map

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a polygon on click of the map and every time I add a new LatLng Object to the array, I assign it to the Polygon object but I realize that the polygon saves older values too and does not get only the values of the newly created array. How can I rerender the polygon once I assign the newly updated array.

```
        function add_point(map, location) {
           upcoming_point = {lat: location.lat(), lng:location.lng() }
           poligon_array.push(upcoming_point)

           if(polygon_array.length>5){
             polygon_array.shift();
           }
           create_Polygon(polygon_array);
         }

         function create_Polygon(polygon_array) {
             var Polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                 paths: polygon_array,
                 strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                 strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                 strokeWeight: 2,
                 fillColor: '#FF0000',
                 fillOpacity: 0.35
               });
              Polygon.setMap(map);

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Polygon.setPath(newArrayOfPoints)` will update the polygon.

```
var polygon;

function add_point(map, location) {
  upcoming_point = {lat: location.lat(), lng:location.lng() }
  poligon_array.push(upcoming_point)

  if(polygon_array.length > 5){
    polygon_array.shift();
  }
  if (polygon) {
    polygon.setPath(polygon_array);
  } else {
    polygon = create_Polygon(polygon_array);
  }
}

function create_Polygon(polygon_array) {
  var Polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygon_array,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  Polygon.setMap(map);
  return Polygon;
}
```